# How do I set unicode as character set in the ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK Visual Studio 2013 projects that are generated by Cmake?

Tags: unicode, cmake, visual-studio-2013, compiler-flags

I am currently using CMake to create a bunch of Visual Studio 2013 projects and it works.
However, the automatically created ZERO_CHECK and ALL_BUILD projects are set to use MBCS by default although I want them to use the Unicode character set.

I did specify the use of the Unicode character set for my projects with the following :

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DUNICODE)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_UNICODE)
```

and it worked. I tried to set the c++ compiler flags with something like :

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /UMBCS /D_UNICODE /DUNICODE")
```

or even :

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DUNICODE)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_UNICODE)
```

before my project settings, but it did not affect ZERO_CHECK and ALL_BUILD at all.
Any Ideas ?

Comment: Any reason why you'd want to change the ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK projects in the first place? They are meta-projects only and the settings there should not have any effect on the code being generated.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Well I am using the Windows MFC and since the ZERO_PROJECT is being compiled before the others, I get this error message : 

Building an MFC project for a non-Unicode character set is deprecated. You must change the project property to Unicode or download an additional library.
See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=286820 for more information.

Using CMake very often, I have to set the character to Unicode manually each time. It is, from my point of view, really annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution.

Thanks to Mike, I realized I was searching in the wrong direction.
Since CMake does not give access to the meta-targets (and I can understand why), one must 
set up the Visual Studio environment to make MFC compile with MBCS.

[This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/08/mfc-support-for-mbcs-deprecated-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) explains why Microsoft did remove native MBCS support for MFC projects and [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40770) provides a download for the MFC-MBCS package.

I'll remain careful with this because I still want my projects to use Unicode, and I'll use CMake flags accordingly. However, ZERO_PROJECT and ALL_BUILD now compile just fine.

It is [Raman Sharma's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603680/mbcs-error-building-mfc-c-project-with-visual-studio-2013) that made me finally see the light.

Thanks you guys, you made my day :D

Best regards !

RL

Answer (score 4):

You could use `cmake --build . -- /p:CharacterSet=Unicode` to build your project with Unicode set as characterset.
In fact by this way you pass a parameter to do this to MSBuild itself, not CMake.

Answer (score 1):

In my case in cmake file [`CMAKE_MFC_FLAG`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MFC_FLAG.html) was set to non-zero value:

```
if(NOT WIN_HEAPINSPECTOR)
    #static link runtime lib
    set(CMAKE_MFC_FLAG 1) 
elseif()
    #dynamic link runtime lib
    set(CMAKE_MFC_FLAG 2) 
endif()
```

I changed it to 0 and then it compiled.

Comment: So, what is the resulting CMake code that works? I cant vote for an answer that says what not to do.

Answer (score 0):

`ZERO_CHECK` and `ALL_BUILD` are meta-targets. All your projects depend on `ZERO_CHECK`, all your projects are dependencies of `ALL_BUILD`, but those two projects themselves do not produce any libraries or executables, thus you need not to care about their build settings.

There could also be other such meta-targets, e.g. `INSTALL` if you used `install()` function.

Comment: Does that mean that with CMake I have no control at all over those meta-targets ?
Is there a way to automatically put Unicode as default character set for any Visual 2013 project? Or will I have to set that parameter by hand each time I regenerate my solution using CMake ? 
Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, you don't have control over those targets. As for adding flags to all targets at once, all you need to do is call `add_definitions()` once in your top-level CMakeLists.txt. All the projects added later via `add_subdirectory()` would inherit those defines.