# errors C2784, C2672 and C2664 in Visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I have following lines in visual studio 2015. It used to be compiled without error in visual studio 2013.

```
const std::basic_regex<wchar_t> e(_T("([eE][-+])(0)(\\d{2})"));
io_string = std::regex_replace(io_string, e, _T("$1$3"));
```

the error is:

error C2664: 'std::basic_regex>::basic_regex(std::basic_regex> &&) noexcept': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [21]' to 'const wchar_t *'

error C2672: 'std::regex_replace': no matching overloaded function found
4>

error C2784: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,std::char_traits<_Elem>,std::allocator<_Other>> std::regex_replace(const _Elem *,const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,const _Elem *,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)': could not deduce template argument for 'const _Elem *' from 'std::string_t'

I know this issue is coming from change tchar.h. Any suggestion for resolving them. I also use CMake for project configuration and the project is running on windows 10.

Comment: If you use `TCHAR` instead of `char_t` or drop the `_T` it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to change your code, you need to ensure that your code is building for [Unicode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxh1wfhz.aspx), so pass `-D_UNICODE` to the compiler. [This post suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011610/how-do-i-set-unicode-as-character-set-in-the-all-build-and-zero-check-visual-stu):

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DUNICODE)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_UNICODE)
```

And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30369285/1270789) illustrates how to enable Unicode through the GUI.

Comment: Using `TCHAR` is terrible advice. Why would you prefer that over `wchar_t`? Windows 98 support? Because that is the only valid reason.

Comment: @rubenvb OK, I deleted my "terrible advice", but I thought leaving the option of compiling either for single byte or double byte was sound. I've not done any Windows for ages, so are single-byte text strings effectively deprecated?

Comment: @KenY-N Thanks for your answer, I have got similar problem for "no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type const std::basic_string<wchar_t>", any idea? (is it better to post another question?) changing compiler is driving me crazy.

Comment: @Ken There is just no reason to not use the `W` version of all API functions. Especially if you are already using it.