# Where is Multibyte MFC Library for Visual Studio 2015 community ed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-2015

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 community ed, made sure I clicked MFC under C++.

Now I can build default wizard generated app, but if I switch to 'not set' char set, it will not compile, complain it needs MBSC libraries.

All links I have found via searches and forums are dead or missing.

Anyone knows where I can find Multibyte MFC Library for Visual Studio 2015 community ed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MBCS Error building MFC C++ project with Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603680/mbcs-error-building-mfc-c-project-with-visual-studio)

Comment: @RossRidge: The proposed duplicate suggests, that the MBCS package is in fact part of the MFC library that comes with Visual Studio 2015 (unlike VS 2013).

Comment: The question, however, is, why would you want to use MBCS encoding (over Unicode) in a new (I take *"wizard generated app"* to mean *"newly created"*) project? MBCS should only ever be used, if you cannot use Unicode, e.g. when maintaining an old project that you cannot convert to Unicode, or if you are linking against libraries that require the MBCS version of MFC to be linked in.